# How could I do a filtered join in Kusto?

Tags: join, filter, left-join, kql

How could I do a filtered join in Kusto?

E.g. I would like to do the following join:

```
a
| join kind=leftouter b on id
```

but also, if `a` has more than one matching rows in `b` I would like to pick only a single row from `b` with the earliest `timestamp`.

Comment: In the future, please validate your code and in addition provide a data sample + required results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let a = datatable(id:int)[1, 2, 3];
let b = datatable(id:int, timestamp:datetime, extra_info:string)
[
    1, datetime(2023-02-28), "Tic"
   ,1, datetime(2023-02-07), "Tac"
   ,1, datetime(2023-02-19), "Toe"
   ,2, datetime(2023-02-10), "Eeny"
   ,2, datetime(2023-02-07), "Meeny"
   ,2, datetime(2023-02-12), "Miny"
   ,2, datetime(2023-02-15), "Moe"
   ,3, datetime(2023-02-01), "Foo"
   ,3, datetime(2023-02-02), "Bar"
];
a
| join kind=leftouter (b | summarize arg_min(timestamp, *) by id) on id
```

| id | id1 | timestamp | extra_info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 | 2023-02-01T00:00:00Z | Foo |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-02-07T00:00:00Z | Tac |
| 2 | 2 | 2023-02-07T00:00:00Z | Meeny |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA33RQUvDMBQH8Hs%20xZ%20eGsmgTRFdZRdBb968DRmpfRtPm0TSDJzsw5tmzFNtcgiP/Hj/B2%20gCIMNehPT7QYquW/ZRbmtFbRC8/YghmS6GaMQ2dIYjf1q0x9NlQJ9x2B27Pa%20HWNgd5BiK5BOanhVpa50s6r0St9LheKV34uJqDlS3WViFki9zsTTheg5Uk3kidzpf3NJeqFFVOuMeNHcZnOdp5nLqify7P0CyUmPJhQiLcGIMz48O3yy6zcD7aM/RgooO5wxHq01gX8IJhx2ll35txmFG4nuBO4lvEvPL1sPz%20nyAQAA)